# Custom Fonts by font face not showing after some days

Tags: css, fonts

I have create custom font family for a font named "Edwardian-Script-ICT". I download the "ttf" formate and convert it by a online font converter [Everything Fonts](https://everythingfonts.com/Everything%20Fonts).

Here is my CSS code.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "Edwardian-Script";
    src: url('font/Edwardian-Script-ITC.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('font/Edwardian-Script-ITC.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/Edwardian-Script-ITC.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/Edwardian-Script-ITC.svg') format('svg')
}
h1{
    font-family:'Edwardian-Script',sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-wight: normal;
}
```

And here is my css folder structure.

```
css
  -font
       -Edwardian-Script-ITC.eot
       -Edwardian-Script-ITC.svg
       -Edwardian-Script-ITC.ttf
       -Edwardian-Script-ITC.woff
   -style.css
```

The font works fine for some days. But after 10-15 days the font don't work and it fallback to normal font. But when I clear my recent browser history it appears again. I don't understand what is the problem. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: whad do you meant under `the font don't work`?

Comment: means its not showing Edwardian-Script font, it shows sans-serif font.

Comment: and if you navigate font file's url on server in browser directly, what happens?

Comment: It start download the font file except the svg formate.

Comment: that's something with caching... What browser do you use?

Comment: I check with two browser Firefox and Google chrome both are giving same  result.

Comment: In chome, with dev-tools check, if fonts were actually loaded on page load, and if not - what reasons of that. It's can be wierd caching- or MIME-related problems.

Comment: Important step 1: make things easier on yourself and only load the WOFF version. [Every browser supports it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff), and has done so for several years now. At the very least, stop using the `ttf` (duplicate of WOFF) and `svg` (obsolete standard, [no longer supported by anything](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font)) versions.